# Is there any $a, b \in \mathbb R, b \ne 0$ such that $\Gamma(a+bi)$ can be evaluated manually?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, gamma-function, complex-integration

Is there any $a, b \in \mathbb R, b \ne 0$ such that $\Gamma(a+bi)$ can be evaluated manually? (Like $\Gamma(\frac 12)$)

If there is/are, could you show me how to calculate it?

I found that $\Gamma(i)$ cannot be calculated by hand, but only can be calculated using computer.

Of course I tried

> $\Gamma(i+1)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^i~e^{-x}~dx$, and then use $x^i=e^{i\ln x}=\cos\ln x+i\sin\ln x$.

But still no clue..

Thanks.

Comment: Could anybody comment on the reason of  a downvote? Where should I improve?

Comment: i think this is a good questions

Comment: How'd you compute $\Gamma\left(\frac 12 \right)$ by hand exactly?

Comment: see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215352/why-is-gamma-left-frac12-right-sqrt-pi

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode see the following link i hope you find some clues https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264034/closed-form-expression-for-the-gamma-function-for-complex-numbers-s-aib-with

Comment: @VincentLaw Wow, thank you for that good material.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Just a thought: In Vincent Law's second link there is a claim that $\arg(\Gamma(z))$ has a closed form. If $\Re(z)=\frac{1}{2}$, then $1-z=\bar{z}$, so $$\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}=\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\Gamma(z)\Gamma(\bar{z})=\Gamma(z)\overline{\Gamma(z)}=|\Gamma(z)|^2,$$ so (if one can find a reference for that particular claim) this might be able to give somewhat of a closed form.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Sounds reasonable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function - related

Comment: @DarkMalthorp https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112682/riemann-siegel-function-and-gamma-function/175734#175734 related?