# Deriving the closed form of Gamma function using Euler-Chi function

Tags: complex-analysis, closed-form, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

**Background #1**

Here is a part of an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/175734/128168) of @Sankyu Kim in MathOverflow.

> Consequently, we get the Euler-chi function
> $\chi(z):=\frac{\zeta(1-z)}{\zeta(z)}$.

And I want to know if Sankyu Kim's last expression is a closed form. (First assuming that its true *though I failed to check the computation*)

> $$\Gamma(z)=\frac{(2\pi)^z}{2\cos(\frac{\pi z}2)}\chi(z)$$

This question is in context of [this comment.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112682/riemann-siegel-function-and-gamma-function/175734#comment440894_175734)

> @ Sangkyu Kim: But the gamma function has no closed form.

If it is a closed form then he may have found the closed form of Gamma function.

**Background #2**

I am gathering information about [this question's(about gamma function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2926317/553404) solution.

**What I know**

$$\xi(z)=\xi(1-z)$$, where $$\xi(z):=π^{-\frac z2}\Gamma(\frac z2)\zeta (z)$$.

**What I've tried to derive the closed form of gamma function**

I used the equation above and derived the following.

$$π^\frac{2z-1}{2}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1-z}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac z2)}\chi(z)=1$$

Further I applied $$\Gamma(z)=\frac{(2\pi)^z}{2\cos(\frac{\pi z}2)}\chi(z)$$ and it gave me function equation. It gave me:

$$\Gamma(z)=\frac{(2\pi)^z}{2\cos(\frac{\pi z}2)}\frac{\Gamma(\frac z2)}{\Gamma(\frac{1-z}2)}π^{-\frac{2z-1}2}$$

This is a functional equation about the  gamma function.

I recently learned that Laplace transform could be used to solve some functional equations like fibonacci, so I tried to find the laplace transform of Gamma function.

I failed. (As it **doesn't** exist)

I just now googled to find the laplace transform of gamma function, but I can't find any. So I launched a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2938166/553404).

If you know how to solve that functional equation, please let me know. Thanks!

**Question:**

> 1. Does $\chi (z)$ have a closed form?
> 2. How do I solve the functional equation above?

**What I mean by closed form**

> a form that the value of the function can be evaluated with finite
> numbers of evaluation s of elementary functions

**What I mean by elementary functions**

Rational, exponential, logarithmic, trigonometric, etc.. (Normal(?) functions)

Comment: You'll have to define "closed form". Anyway, what formula(s) do you know for chi?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: @GerryMyerson May I drfine "closed form" as "a form that the value of the function can be evaluated with finite numbers of evaluation s of elementary function s"?

Comment: OK, but then you have to say which are the elementary functions. Also, you haven't told me what formula(s) you know for chi.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Edited my question.

Comment: For $\Re(s) >0$, $\Gamma(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $e^{-e^{-u}}$ and  $e^{-e^{-u}}e^{-\sigma u}$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $\Gamma(\sigma+i\omega)$. Also looking at a proof of the reflection formula  $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(s-1)\sin(\pi s) = \pi$ might be interesting

Comment: OK, so, it's clear that $\Gamma$ has a closed form if and only if $\chi$ does. Given that $\Gamma$ has been around for a long time, has been studied intensively, and no one has found a closed form for it, my money would be on the negative.