# What is the Laplace transform of gamma function?

Tags: laplace-transform, gamma-function

What is $$\mathfrak L (\Gamma(z))$$? And how can it be derived?

$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^t dt$$

$$\mathfrak L(\Gamma(z)) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^t dt e^{-sz} dz$$

Yes, of course I tried to find on google but I could only find something like laplace transform *using* the gamma function, and *inverse* Laplace transform of gamma function, etc..

Also I tried by myself, but no fruit..

This result may be applied to solving gamma functional equation, which is in [another question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2937647/553404)

Comment: It is meaningless. Besides the pole at the origin, $\Gamma(z)$ grows too fast for $\Gamma(z)e^{-sz}$ to be integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeah, I remember having failed because of that..

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How about unilateral laplace transform at $\mathbb R^-$?

Comment: Still you have to deal with a lot of poles, so $\int_{\mathbb{R}^-}\Gamma(z)e^{sz}\,dz$ have to be considered in principal value. In that sense it might be convergent, but what is the actual use of such transform?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio As an attempt to solve the functional equation in this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2937647/553404)

Comment: I.e. you want to prove Legendre's duplication formula through the Laplace transform. Much better to consider the **inverse** Laplace transform of the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Anyway I believe that the Legendre duplication formula is simpler to prove by integrating twice, then exponentiating, the almost-trivial duplication formula for the trigamma function $\psi'(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+z)^2}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't find it because it does not exist:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{e^{an}}=\infty \quad \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Yeah, I remember having failed because of that..

Comment: How about unilateral laplace transform  at $\mathbb R^-$?