# Prove that $e^{\frac12i\,\text{gd}(\pi t)}\cos^\frac12(\text{gd}(\pi t))=\frac{1+i}{e^{\pi z}+i}e^{\frac{\pi z}2}$

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, exponential-function, gamma-function

This question was derived from [this post about Gamma function.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/175734/128168)

Juan said:

> $$ \Gamma\left(\frac12+it\right)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\cosh\pi
>  t}}\exp\left\{i\left(2\vartheta(t)+t\log(2\pi)+\arctan\tanh\frac{\pi t}2\right)\right\}. $$

Sankyu kim said:

> $$\Gamma\left(\frac12+iz\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}(1+i)(2\pi)^{iz}}{e^{\pi z}+i}e^{\frac{\pi z}2+2i\vartheta(z)}\qquad \forall z\in\mathbb{C}.$$

Sankyu Kim derived above by generalizing Juan's answer.

If it is correct, it would help to solving my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2926317/553404), so I tried to follow it myself. However what made me suspicious was that no one voted on his answer. [So I added comments to his answer but no gain.](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3906/128168)

Anyway while I was following Sankyu kim's method I couldn't clarify the missing link between his expressions.

I finally stuck here;

> Prove that $$e^{\frac12i\,\text{gd}(\pi t)}\cos^\frac12(\text{gd}(\pi t))=\frac{1+i}{e^{\pi z}+i}e^{\frac{\pi z}2}.$$

**Materials that will help you**

[Gudermanian function $\text{gd}(z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function)

[Riemann–Siegel theta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function)

**Details about what I did**

By Gudermanian function's properties, $\arctan\tanh\dfrac{πt}2=\dfrac {\text{gd}(πt)}2$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\Gamma\left(\frac 12 +i z\right) &=\frac{\sqrt{π}}{\sqrt{\cosh πz}}\exp\left\{i\left(2\vartheta(z)+z \ln{2π} + \frac{\text{gd}(\pi z)}2\right)\right\}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{π}}{\sqrt{\cosh πz}}e^{2i\vartheta(z)}e^{iz \ln{2π}}e^{\frac12i\,\text{gd}(\pi z)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{π}}{\sqrt{\cosh πz}}e^{2i\vartheta(z)}{(2π)}^{iz}e^{\frac12i\,\text{gd}(\pi z)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{π}{(2π)}^{iz}}{\sqrt{\cosh πz}}e^{2i\vartheta(z)} e^{\frac12i\,\text{gd}(\pi z)}\\
&=\sqrt{π}{(2π)}^{iz}e^{2i\vartheta(z)}e^{\frac12i\,\text{gd}(\pi z)}{\text{sech}}^{\frac 12}(πz)\\
&=\sqrt{π}{(2π)}^{iz}e^{2i\vartheta(z)}e^{\frac12i\,\text{gd}(\pi z)}{\cos}^{\frac 12}(\text{gd}(πz)).
\end{align*}

**Then I stuck here.**

Anyone who would lead me to the end? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Claim:** Consider the principal square root function, for any $x\in\Bbb C$,
>   $$\left(e^{i\,\text{gd}\ x}\cos\text{gd}\ x\right)^{\frac12}=\frac{1+i}{e^{x}+i}e^{\frac x2}.$$

Recall the Euler's formula

> $$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x,$$

we have
\begin{align*}
e^{i\,\text{gd}\ x}\cos\text{gd}\ x&=\left(\cos\text{gd}\ x+i\sin\text{gd}\ x\right)\cos\text{gd}\ x\\
&=\left(\ \text{sech}\ x+i\tanh x\right)\,\text{sech}\ x\\
&=\frac{1+i\sinh x}{\cosh^2x}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-i\sinh x}\\
&=\frac{2i}{e^x+2i-e^{-x}}\\
&=\frac{2i}{\left(e^{\frac x2}+ie^{-\frac x2}\right)^2}.
\end{align*}
Consider the principal square root function, we have $\sqrt{2i}=1+i$ and
\begin{align*}
\left(e^{i\,\text{gd}\ x}\cos\text{gd}\ x\right)^{\frac12}&=\frac{\sqrt{2i}}{\sqrt{\left(e^{\frac x2}+ie^{-\frac x2}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{1+i}{e^{\frac x2}+i e^{-\frac x2}}\\
&=\frac{1+i}{e^{x}+i}e^{\frac x2}.
\end{align*}